# Email Alert when a record's status not changed

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert

Is it possible to build a solution that will send out an email when the status of a Case Record has not been changed for a certain amount of time ?..let us say 24 hours.

Comment: Have you looked at using Escalation Rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at a time based work flow rule? Should it be for any status or just the first one (new I presume). Assuming it's just for new the work flow should fire on creation when the status is new. Action is to send an email in 24hours time.

If the status changes so that the case no longer meets those criteria the email will be removed from the time based work flow queue.  Which can be seen under monitor.

(I wanted to post this as a comment first but didn't have permission to).

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty new to SF and so was not aware of this functionality. Will it be an issue if large number of Cases to be monitored..say like 10000-12000 Cases. Will any governor limit will be hit ?

Comment: Possibly with that number, there is a limit on time triggers:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_workflow.htm. You may want to look at escalation at Nick mentioned above. (Sorry for edits, nightmare on phone).